# Nextcloud Download Large File Downloads stop every 1GB

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, nextcloud

I've been running nextcloud on arch linux for months and have never gotten large files to work properly. Gotten dozens of suggestions that haven't worked. When I try and upload a large file it says something like "Error when assembling chunks. Status code 504." It will still upload fine despite the warning. When you try and download the large file it will stop every 1GB. Running uwsgi as the application server and nginx as web server. It stops at exactly 1GB so I'm sure it's not a timing issue and more of a max upload file size issue.

Journal when trying to upload large file: Apr 05 20:06:58 thinkArch nginx[287526]: 2022/04/05 20:06:58 [error] 287526#287526: *63144 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: 192.168.50.1, server: cloud.atavismxi.com, request: "GET /remote.php/webdav/AtavismXI/AtavismXI-Installer-1.61.zip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/uwsgi/nextcloud.sock:", host: "cloud.atavismxi.com"

Below are my conf files. Some of the suggestions other people made are still in them. Some of the suggestions are gone. But I've tried a lot of different nginx settings.

php.ini: https://pastebin.com/gzdxGBqD

```
post_max_size = 5G
```

nextcloud.ini (for uwsgi) https://pastebin.com/18e1Fwip

```
php-set = upload_max_filesize=10G
```

nginx.conf: https://pastebin.com/X8GWikHj

```
    client_max_body_size 0;
```

Comment: Try with the the `upload` module https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/.